# PHP XPath - troubles reading node attributes with "evaluate"

Tags: php, xpath

I need to read the "id" attributes but I get either empty strings OR a string containing "one" depending on the XPath expression used.

I intentionally use the "query" method to get the DOMNodeList with  nodes, then I want to work with them. Please check the following code:

```
<?php
$xml = '
    <ROOT>
        <MEMBER id="one" />
        <MEMBER id="two" />
    </ROOT>
';


$dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$members = $xpath->query('/ROOT/MEMBER');  // object of class DOMNodeList

foreach ($members as $member) {
    echo($dom->saveXML($member));  // displays <MEMBER id="one"/> and <MEMBER id="two"/> as expected
    $id = $xpath->evaluate('string(/MEMBER/@id)', $member);   // let's read the id attribute
    var_dump($id);  // returns string(0) "" in both cases  - how come?
    $id = $xpath->evaluate('string(//MEMBER/@id)', $member);   // should make no difference
    var_dump($id);  // string(3) "one" in both cases
}
```

Comment: in foreach you are already on `MEMBER` context so instead of `/MEMBER/@id` use only `@id` hope you will get desire output.

Comment: Yep, that works. But `MEMBER` is a root node so `/MEMBER/@id` should work as well. I am still confused...

Comment: In your input XML root node is `ROOT`

Comment: In $dom it is `ROOT`, in $member the root node is `MEMBER`.

Comment: if you are using `/MEMBER/@id` it means your Current context should be like 
 `<MEMBER><MEMBER id="one" /><MEMBER id="two" /></MEMBER>`

Comment: ??? I do not understand. I am not sure what you mean by current context.

Back to the DOMNodeList. Every `foreach` run creates a DOMElement instance ($member).The saveXML() method outputs `<MEMBER id="one"/>` for first $member. So <MEMBER> is the root node of $member, right?

And according to https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp I should be able to use expression `/MEMBER/@id` to get the attribute of the root node.

Answer (score 0):

in foreach you are already on `MEMBER` context so instead of `/MEMBER/@id` use only `@id` hope you will get desire output.

Actually in `foreach ($members as $member)` there are two `<MEMBER id="one" />` and `<MEMBER id="two" />` will the context so you already on `MEMBER` element you just need to pick `@id` from current context.

If you will print `$member` then you will know what is storing in this context then the picture will be clear.

Please accept the answer if it work for you..